# How to combine audio and video from different streams using ffmpeg and timestamps

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I was wondering if there is a way to add video and audio coming from different streams. For the background, I have audio and video coming from different devices sending (byte) data to my nodejs server. A message looks like this:

```js
{
  id: <some-identifier>,  
  timestamp: <DateTime>,
  data: <base64-encoded-bytes>
}
```

I was successfully able to record both video and audio in separate files using ffmpeg.

```bash
ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -r ${fps} -i - -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale 5 -r ${fps} ${outputVideoPath}`
ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 -i pipe:0 -y -f wav ${audioFilePath}
```

For the video I also added a `.srt` file which is generated at runtime with the sent timestamps, though the subtitles are added after the stream is closed.

My question is: Can I use the sent timestamps to combine both streams (at runtime or later)? It is important to mention, that the streams might not be started at the same time, therefore just combining both won't work.